# Caching of objects

Tags: google-apps-script

I currently struggle with the publicCache method of Google Apps Script. My scenario is the following. I built a script to calculate distances between various (German) zip codes and five fixed places.
To speed up the script I want to calculates the coordinates of the five places only once then store the result and access it in the calculation function. As I understood it Google Apps Script does not support manipulation of global variables, so I wanted to go for the cache method.

The problem is, that I cannot manage to store the object with the coordinates in the cache. It only returns "object Object". What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all.
Alex

```
function cityCoordinates() {

  var cities = ["Frankfurt", "Munich", "Hamburg", "Cologne", "Berlin"]
  var cities_zips = ["60329, Germany", "80335, Germany", "20355, Germany", "50667, Germany", "10557, Germany"]
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();

  for (k = 0; k < cities_zips.length; k++) {
    var city_coordinates = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(cities_zips[k]);

    Logger.log(city_coordinates.results[0].geometry.location) // returns ie {lng=13.365317, lat=52.5231724}


    cache.put([k], city_coordinates, 1500)        
    }


  Logger.log(cache.get('1')) // returns [object Object]

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to store a JSON object in the cache. Use `JSON.stringfy(city_coodinates)` to store and then `JSON.parse(cache.get('1'))`

```
function cityCoordinates() {

  var cities = ["Frankfurt", "Munich", "Hamburg", "Cologne", "Berlin"];
  var cities_zips = ["60329, Germany", "80335, Germany", "20355, Germany", "50667, Germany", "10557, Germany"];
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();

  for (k = 0; k < cities_zips.length; k++) {
    var city_coordinates = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(cities_zips[k]);

    Logger.log(city_coordinates.results[0].geometry.location); // returns ie {lng=13.365317, lat=52.5231724}


    cache.put([k], JSON.stringify(city_coordinates), 1500);    
  };


  Logger.log(cache.get('1')); // returns the stringfied object

  Logger.log(JSON.parse(cache.get('1'))); // returns the object

}
```